# Specify multiple base packages for spring data mongo

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm specifying single base package for scanning mongo repositories

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.example.conditions.dao"/>
```

Now I've another module included in my project and I want to be able to specify that package also to be scanned by spring for repositories.

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.example.cf.common.dao"/>
```

How do I specify both packages to be scanned by spring?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this:

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.example.conditions.dao, com.example.cf.common.dao"/>
```

In case you decide to use Java annotation configuration:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { "com.example.conditions.dao", "com.example.cf.common.dao" })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html) for a full answer but the point is to make all packages like com.example.*.dao , so you could do

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.example.*.conditions.dao" />
```